# A question on limit of functions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions such that$ f_n \to f$ uniformly on $\mathbb R$. Suppose that $x_n\to x_0$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x_n)=f(x_0)$.

Let me know if I should format it better! This question seems so straightforward that I don't know what definition I'm supposed to employ...

Comment: You need to show that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geqslant n_0$, you have $\lvert f_n(x_n) - f(x_0)\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon$. Use that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly, and that hence $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes, I used the limit definition, but I am unsure of how to proceed after that... Since f is continuous, by definition then the limit definition for $f_n and  $x_n apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;\epsilon >0\;$:

$$|f_n(x_n)-f(x_0)|=|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)+f(x_n)-f(x_0)|\le$$

$$|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|+|f(x_n)-f(x_0)|$$

For the first summand in the second line above there exists $\;N_1\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. it is less than $\;\frac\epsilon2\;$ *for any* $\;x_n\;$ as long as $\;n>N_1\;$, and for the second summand there exists $\;N_2\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. it is less than $\;\frac\epsilon2\;$ as long as $\;n>N_2\;$ by continuity (why?) ...and we're done.

Comment: So clean, thanks. As for the second summand, is it because we can just say:

$f(x_n) -> f(x_0)$

Comment: Yes, right: because of the continuity of $\;f\;$ as uniform limit of continuous functions!